# Is there any other way to set the properties of the interface in gbdus besides using this method？

Tags: glib, dbus, gdbus

Is there any other way to set the properties of the interface in gbdus besides using org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties：

```
g_dbus_connection_call_sync(conn,
                                "org.example",
                                "/org/example/object",
                                "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
                                "Set",
                                g_variant_new(),
                                NULL,
                                G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE,
                                -1,
                                NULL,
                                &error);
```

Is there a more convenient API?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, which may be more convenient if the interface you’re using has a lot of methods or properties, is to generate a [`GDBusProxy`](https://docs.gtk.org/gio/class.DBusProxy.html) wrapper for it using `gdbus-codegen`. Then call methods on that generated wrapper to set properties.

[Here is an example](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gio/stable/ch35s05.html#gdbus-example-gdbus-codegen) of how to use `gdbus-codegen`.